# How to change a class in Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, class

I'm using a Wordpress theme and I want to change a social icon by changing the class from: "meta-icon ion-social-instagram" to "meta-icon ion-social-linkedin" Can I do this in the Additional CSS box or does it need to be changed in the theme editor?

Thx

Comment: It most likely needs to changed in the theme editor. But would be nice if you show your code and what you wnt to achive.

Comment: What theme are you using and which element are you trying to edit? You mostly require to update something in the theme editor.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll edit it in the theme editor. I've not used Wordpress before so wasn't sure what the best practice was